# selecting year only in date format from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

hey guys I'm trying to select a date from mysql and the format is date("F j, Y"); but I'm just selecting the year of the date and my field is varchar type and heres my php:

```
session_start();
$school_id = $_SESSION['school_id'];
$section_id = $_POST['section_id'];
$today  = date("F j, Y");


$select_grades_deped = "SELECT * 
                        FROM deped_grade_archive 
                        WHERE school_id='$school_id'
                        AND section_id='$section_id'
                        AND submission_date ='$today' ";


$query_check_grades= mysql_query($select_grades_deped) or die (mysql_error());

$check_count = mysql_num_rows($query_check_grades);

if($check_count == 0){
    $return['checked'] = "0";
}
else{
    $return['checked'] = "1";
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

and it returns 0, is there a way to select a year only from mysql?. I'm noob in selecting dates so please help, and I'm aware that mysql is deprecated and gonna be switching to mysqli after this project, so please help guys. tnx in advance
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19491573/edit

Comment: If you used the proper data type for your field (date) this would be trivial to do.

Comment: i know. but i didnt made the db thats why im suffering now.

Comment: I've been there. You have my sympathies!

Comment: What format is the date in MySQL in?

Comment: How is it stored in your database? as string?

Comment: Webnet varchar bro! John Conde: tnx bro

Comment: I tested year(date_string) it returns true year, is that what you want?

Comment: but it is stored in DB as varchar

Comment: i change the data type in to date and yet its still 0 in mysql_numrows
http://pastebin.com/J8qfyZ88

Answer (score 1):

If the last 4 digits of the field is the year you could do:

```
RIGHT(FIELDNAME, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you have a field called my_date and that field is date (or datetime), then you can do:

```
SELECT year(my_date) AS my_year FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data type is varchar.

Comment: i change the data type in to date and yet its still 0 in mysql_numrows pastebin.com/J8qfyZ88

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(submission_date ,'%Y') = 2013
```

This should accommodate your date being stored as a varchar

Answer (score 0):

You could use `"SELECT RIGHT('name_of_date_column_that_is_varchar', 4) FROM table_name"`

This will give you the right 4 chars of the field and hence the year which is what you want.